# Definition not found for C# MVC model property

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have this model:

```
public class RamalModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string  Nome { get; set; }
    public int Numero { get; set; }
}
```

And I create a partial view:

```
@model RamalAguia.Models.RamalModel

<div>

    <h4>@Model.Nome</h4>

    <span>@Model.Numero</span>
    <hr />

</div>
```

In my controller I'm using it:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    RamaDb _db = new RamaDb();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _db.Ramais.ToList();

        return View(model.ToList());
    }
}
```

But when I try to put:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_Ramal", Model.Nome , new ViewDataDictionary());
```

It doesn't work and shows this error:

> Error 1   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   does not contain a definition for 'Nome' and no extension method
>   'Nome' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   c:\dev\Teste\RamalAguia\RamalAguia\Views\Home\Index.cshtml  9   37  RamalAguia

Someone can help me? Thanks

Comment: just to make sure but 'Nome' is supposed to be 'Nome' and not 'Name' right?

Comment: your `Model` is a `List`. There is no property on `List` called `Nome`.  You need to loop over your `List` and create a partial for each item.

Answer (score 2):

Your model is `List<RamaModel>` and you in

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_Ramal", Model.Nome , new ViewDataDictionary());
```

trying to get from variable type `RamaModel` not from list.

For render first elemet you can use:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_Ramal", Model[0].Nome , new ViewDataDictionary());
```

Or for show all ramas in list:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.RenderPartial("_Ramal", item.Nome , new ViewDataDictionary());
}
```

**EDIT**

In View

Change

```
@model RamalAguia.Models.RamalModel
```

to

```
@model List<RamalAguia.Models.RamalModel>
```

And in controller

```
return View(model.ToList());
```

`.ToList()` is unnecessary.

Comment: I tried but shows a error again:'RamalAguia.Models.RamalList' does not contain a definition for 'Nome' and no extension method 'Nome' accepting a first argument of type 'RamalAguia.Models.RamalList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @FelipeRenan I update my answer, try this. I missed view

Comment: Doesn't work :( Error: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @FelipeRenan romove `@Html.RenderPartial("_Ramal", item.Nome , new ViewDataDictionary());` and try. If this works this is another problem and another question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

In my partial view:

```
@model List<RamalAguia.Models.RamalModel>   

@{
    foreach(var item in Model) {
        <h4>@item.Nome</h4>       
        <span>@item.Numero</span>
        <hr />
    }
}
```

And in my Index:

```
@model List<RamalAguia.Models.RamalModel>


        @Html.Partial("_Ramal", Model);
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to accomplish but I'm assuming you want to display a list of `RamalModel` on a page. In your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _db.Ramais.ToList();   
        return View(model);
    }
```

And when rendering your partial:

```
@model List<RamalAguia.Models.RamalModel>
...
@Html.RenderPartial("_Ramal", Model, new ViewDataDictionary());
```

and inside your partial, to loop through the list:

```
@model List<RamalAguia.Models.RamalModel>    

foreach(var item in Model) {
   <h4>@item.Nome</h4>       
   <span>@item.Numero</span>
   <hr />
}
```

**Another approach**:

You can loop through the list and render a partial view for each one, depends on what you want to achieve:

```
@model List<RamalAguia.Models.RamalModel>    

    foreach(var item in Model) {
       @Html.RenderPartial("_Ramal", item, new ViewDataDictionary());
    }
```

Comment: I tried too but shows a error again: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Okay but that's a totally different error, you may want to figure that one out first.